# How to listen clipboard event?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

How to listen events, when user tries to copy with mouse or with Ctrl + C from browser url (locationbar). It is should work only through javascript. Sorry, but i haven't any ideas to it and i can't show any code. The main idea it is replace value from clipboard.

Comment: You can't intercept location bar keypresses, afaik. Javascript has no access to stuff outside the document window.

Answer (score 4):

A very quick [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20event%20listener%20clipboard)...

Note: This will only work within the confines of the DOM. **Not** the address bar.

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Hello, world!');
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', '<b>Hello, world!</b>');
    e.preventDefault(); // We want our data, not data from any selection, to be written to the clipboard
});
```

Reference: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy)